# WinSCP session not ending with CLOSE command

Tags: session, winscp

I am currently writing a script that calls WinSCP, connects an SFTP session, transfers a group of files from a local server to a remote server, closes the connection, then exits. 
I see multiple WinSCP.exe processes that left running after every run. What is wrong with my syntax?

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /log="C:\imports\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /command "open sftp://UN@sftp1.vendor.com/writable/ -hostkey=""ssh-......"" -privatekey=""C:\mykeys\UN_private.ppk"""  "put -latest C:\import\customers\*.csv /imports/*.csv" "close" "exit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Single run of `WinSCP.com` only ever runs a single instance of `WinSCP.exe`, never more.

`WinSCP.com` also runs in the same Windows job as `WinSCP.exe`. So if `WinsCP.com` terminates, Windows makes sure that `WinSCP.exe` is terminated too, no matter how wrong you write your script or what bug can be in WinSCP itself preventing an explicit `WinSCP.exe` termination.

So it's quite likely that there's something else, that causes the `WinSCP.exe` processes be left behind, not your script. Or your description of the problem is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

My code used ^ to separate the commands in separate lines.
Removed `"close" ^` from the code.
Moved "exit" next to last command. For some reason it didn't like that I formatted the batch file with ^.

Here is the old code

```
"put -latest C:\import\customers\*.csv /imports/*.csv" ^
"close" ^
 "exit"
```

and the working code -

```
"put -latest C:\import\customers\*.csv /imports/*.csv" "exit"
```

Comment: See WinSCP FAQ [Why are some scripting commands specified on WinSCP command-line in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)